# Spyder - touchpad scroll does not work

Tags: python, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, ide

I use the scroll function with my mouse and it works fine. But either in script, or in terminal sections of Spyder, I can't use the touchpad for scrolling. I do not experience any problems with my touchpad in other programs like Word, Chrome etc. Is there any option for this in Spyder, specific for touchpad?

I am using Lenovo Legion Y520, Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem with Spyder and also with the TeXstudio LaTeX editor (Windows 10 on Lenovo Laptop).

Drivers were not the problem in my case (I double checked them were properly updated). I could solve the issue as pointed out in [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/two-finger-scrolling-not-working-after-windows/22f6ad5c-20de-449d-bdaf-0f67bf3c245d), the second answer. Briefly:

- Search "regedit" in start
- on the left tab: HKEY_CURRENT_USER, then
- Software
- Elantech
- Smartpad
- enable "ScrollControl_Mode" (right click, edit and set to 1)

It worked for me, hope it helps!

---

**EDIT**

I assumed that your device mounts an Elan pointing device. Otherwise I don't know whether for in the case if your manufacturer the "Elantech" folder in the list above has another name. Hope it helps anyway