# Touchpad scroll does not work in Whatsapp Web Application

Tags: mouse, touchpad, scrolling, web-whatsapp

I am using Whatsapp Web via its desktop application. It was running smoothly until I install the latest update for Windows. Now, I cannot two-finger scroll with my touchpad (ELAN) although it works with an external mouse. My touchpad scroll works well in all other platforms. What could be the reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: This is again a valid solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1459000/spyder-touchpad-scroll-does-not-work

Comment: Yes this is the same link that I provided. @Karu

Comment: Bluh, sorry. Forgot to turn off the auto message from review