# Touchpad scroll does not work in Spyder and Anaconda

Tags: python, touchpad, scrolling, anaconda

I have an older Thinkpad R61 laptop that I still use and it comes with Alps touchpad and has Windows 7 x64 installed. I have an Anaconda x64 distribution installed along with the Spyder IDE. For some reason touchpad scrolling does not work in either Spyder IDE or Anaconda. At the same time, touchpad scrolling works just fine in Windows, Word, Excel, Firefox and all other third party programs that I have on that computer.

I have tried several different versions of Anaconda distribution and several different versions of the touchpad driver but I could not get scrolling to work. I have also noticed the windows registry section: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Alps\Apoint\Exceptions that seems to contain window classes names (see the picture below) that I presume are treated somehow differently by the driver and I have tried adding new entries there like qWidget, but again it made no difference.

[registry screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JP47.png)

I would much appreciate any suggestions on how I can try resolving this scrolling issue, as I am out of ideas. While one can live without scrolling in Spyder, it would be nice to make it work.

My question seems to be very similar to this one [Spyder - touchpad scroll does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/1459000/spyder-touchpad-scroll-does-not-work) but since I have slightly different hardware (Alps rather than Elan touchpad), the solution proposed in the referenced question does not seem to be applicable to my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. It's probably not the optimal one (a more optimal solution, in my opinion, would involve specifying window classes, etc), but it works. Go to "C:\Program Files\Apoint2K" and edit "tp4table.dat" file by inserting the 2 following strings under the "pass 1 rules":

```
; Python

*,*,pythonw.exe,*,*,*,WheelStd,1,9
```